# Use conditional formatting to highlight a cell that represents a date within 6 months of a date in another cell

Tags: excel

I have a column with dates of hire, I then also have columns that represent months. Every row is a different employee. I want to highlight cells in the "months" column that are within 6 months of the date of hire. I can't figure out how to make conditional formatting compare the two dates in the two separate cells and then format a third cell based on that date being within 6 months of the DOH. Does that make sense?

Col c = Date of Hire

Col e-p = months (Oct-Sep, they are in date format)

I would like the cells in Col c to be highlighted for staff who have a date of hire that is within 6 months of the date headers in Col c.

Hopefully I have explained clearly enough. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: The solution depends on how you have the headers stored. Can you post an image of your workbook and desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear any existing CF from ColumnC, select it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(C1>EOMONTH(MAX($E$1:$P$1),-19),C1<EOMONTH(MAX($E$1:$P$1),6))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

May require adjustment for the day of the month chosen in cell P1 and for your interpretation of "within" and "six months".